# Object literal may only specify known properties - Does not exist in type 'SaveOptions'

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I am using graphQL Apollo, Postgres, Express.js to build a small website.
I am selecting an existing `profile` and I would like to update its `firstName` and `lastName`

**My code**

```
  const profile = await Profile.findOne({where: { user: payload!.userId}}) 
  if (profile) {
    console.log(profile) <-- It returns correctly the profile I am looking for
    await profile.save({
      firstName, <-- Error here
      lastName
    })
```

However, I get the following error:

> Argument of type '{ firstName: string; lastName: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SaveOptions'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'firstName' does not exist in type 'SaveOptions'.ts(2345)

Error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7BEd.jpg

I think the problem is with the **type** of profile which is **Profile | undefined**.
Where **Profile** is inferred from the typeORM entity:

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity("profile")
export class Profile extends BaseEntity{

    @Field(()=>String)
    @Column({ nullable: true }) 
    firstName: string;
    
    @Field(()=>String)
    @Column({ nullable: true }) 
    lastName: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From a quick glance at their docs it seems to me like save doesn't take the new data as input.

Rather, they modify the object directly (so profile.firstName = firstName) and then call save without arguments.

The argument to save is for the SaveOptions which configure how the save should be done, see here: https://typeorm.delightful.studio/interfaces/_repository_saveoptions_.saveoptions.html

So TypeScript is saying that the property firstName doesn't exist in SaveOptions (which is true) and that's what you're passing in to the save function which expects a valid SaveOptions object.